# Hide form and Div class from drop down box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down box which once selected displays specific form elements, this works perfect but as soon as i add a div class to the elements (drop down boxes) the css class still shows even if that specific element isn't selected.

Is it possible to hide the css class along with the form element, below is my code.

Javascript

```
   function check() {
var dropdown = document.getElementById("filtercriteria");
var current_value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

if (current_value == "page_name") {
    document.getElementById("contains").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("term").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("countries").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("postcodes").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("repeater").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("visitor_type").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("page_visits").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("pvisits_value").style.display = "none";
}
```

HTML Drop down select Box

```
 <select id="filtercriteria" onChange="check(this);" >
 <option value="select">Select</option>
 <option value="page_name">Page Name</option>
 <option value="postcode">Postcode</option>
 <option value="country">Country</option>
 <option value="search_term">Search Term</option>
 <option value="referrer">Refferer</option>
 <option value="country">Country</option>
 <option value="search_term">Search Term</option>
 <option value="referrer">Referrer</option>
 <option value="page_visits">Page Visits</option>
 <option value="repeater">Repeater</option>
 <option value="owner">Owner</option>
 <option value="visitor_type">Visitor Type</option>
 </select>
```

First Hidden Element with the Div Class that shows even if this option isn't selected.

```
 <div id="pagename">
   <div class="select-div">
     <select id="contains" name="contains" display="none" class="hideme">
        <option value="contains">contains</option>
        <option value="exact">exact</option>
     </select>
   </div>
  <input name="term" id="term" type="text" class="hideme" display='none' />

 </div>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u2puF/2

Comment: Could you able to supply a [tag:jsfiddle] demo?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it's supposed to work. Please clarify. Fiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u2puF/2

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: Your `option` elements will each need an `id` attribute if you plan on using `getElementById()`